# Django: Iterating over a Nested Dictionary

Tags: python, html, django, dictionary

This is the dictionary I would like to iterate over:

```
{
    '04/14/2018': {
        '12:15': {
            'Club 1': {
                'venue_address': 'Address 1',
                'venue_webaddress': 'http://www.address1.com/line-up',
                'show_data': {
                    7968: {
                        'price': '20',
                        'payment_webaddress': 'http://www.club1.com/reservation/',
                        'show_title': 'Street 1',
                        'acts': [('Act 1', None, None), ('Act 2', None, None), ('Act 3', None, None), ('Act 4', None, None), ('Act 5', None, None), ('Act 6', None, None)]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        '03:00': {
            'Club 2': {
                'venue_address': 'Address 2',
                'venue_webaddress': 'https://www.club2.com/',
                'show_data': {
                    7879: {
                        'price': 'None',
                        'payment_webaddress': 'https://www.club2.com/checkout',
                        'show_title': 'Show Title 2',
                        'acts': [(None, None, None)]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        '04:00': {
            'Club 3': {
                'venue_address': 'Address 3',
                'venue_webaddress': 'http://www.club3.com/',
                'show_data': {
                    7703: {
                        'price': '17',
                        'payment_webaddress': 'https://www.webaddress.com',
                        'show_title': 'Show Title Club 3',
                        'acts': [(None, None, None)]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        '05:00': {
            'Club 4': {
                'venue_address': 'Address 4',
                'venue_webaddress': 'https://club4.com/',
                'show_data': {
                    7834: {
                        'price': 'None',
                        'payment_webaddress': 'https://club4.com/checkout',
                        'show_title': 'Show Title 4',
                        'acts': [(None, None, None)]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        '05:45': {
            'Club 5': {
                'venue_address': 'Address 5',
                'venue_webaddress': 'http://www.club5.com/',
                'show_data': {
                    7569: {
                        'price': '25',
                        'payment_webaddress': 'https://www.clubaddress5.com',
                        'show_title': 'Club Address 5',
                        'acts': [('Act 1', None, None)]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        '06:00': {
            'Club 6': {
                'venue_address': 'Club Address 6',
                'venue_webaddress': 'https://www.club6.com/',
                'show_data': {
                    7881: {
                        'price': 'None',
                        'payment_webaddress': 'https://www.club6.com',
                        'show_title': 'Show Title 6',
                        'acts': [(None, None, None)]
                    },
                    7880: {
                        'price': 'None',
                        'payment_webaddress': 'https://www.club6.com/checkout',
                        'show_title': 'Show Title 7',
                        'comedians': [(None, None, None)]
                    }
                }
            },
            'Club 8': {
                'venue_address': 'Club Address 8',
                'venue_webaddress': 'http://club8.com/',
                'show_data': {
                    7809: {
                        'price': 'None',
                        'payment_webaddress': 'https://club8.com',
                        'show_title': 'ACT TITLE 8',
                        'acts': [(None, None, None)]
                    }
                }
            },
```

The code I'm using in the Django view is the following:

```
dataset_2_ = sorted(dataset_)

context = {'show_dates': dataset_2_, 'show_dataset': dataset_, 'title': title}

return render(request, "pages/pages.html", context)
```

The reason I pass two datasets is because when I sort the first one in order to iterate by date it loses all of the nested data.

This is my display code:

```
{% block content %}

    {% for date_key in show_dates %}
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-sm-1'></div>
            <div class='col-sm-3'>
                <h2>{{ date_key }} </h2>
            </div>
            <div class='col-sm-8'></div>
        </div>
        {% for time_key in show_dataset.items.date_key %}
            <div class='row'>
                <div class='col-sm-2'></div>
                <div class='col-sm-2'>
                    <h3>{{ time_key }} </h3>
                </div>
                <div class='col-sm-8'></div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

I thought this code would produce:

> 4/14/2018
>
> 12:15 
>   3:00
>   4:00
>
> 4/15/2018
>   ...

Except that it hasn't and I don't understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{{ show_dataset.items }}` is the iterator through your dictionary, so you can't subscript it with the `date_key` expecting to fetch the dict item.

Also you can't just use a variable to lookup a dict item by key in Django templates.

What you need is first create a lookup filter yourself. Inside a *template_tags* directory in one of your apps, create this filter in a file *util_filters.py*:

```
@register.filter(name='lookup')
def lookup(struct, key):
"""Return element of a list or dict using a variable."""

if isinstance(struct, (list, QuerySet)) and isinstance(key, int) and len(struct) > key:
    return struct[key]
elif isinstance(struct, dict):
    return struct.get(key, '')
else:
    return ''
```

Then in your template:

```
{% load util_filters %}
...
{% for time_key in show_dataset|lookup:date_key %}
```

Note that this works if you only need the keys (as shown in your example). If you also need to access the values for each `time_key`, you'll have to write a different filter that returns the (key, value) pairs to iterate through (`items()`).

Comment: Thank you.  I'm new to Django.  For this example, do I have to create a template_tags directory and if so do I have to register it anywhere (settings.py, the admin module, etc.)?  Also, I will need to return other dictionaries.  You allude to it in your answer.  The documentation for filters is sparce.  Would you mind making it explicit?

Comment: See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-template-tags/) for more details. But the gist of it is: Create a `templatetags` directory at the top level of your app (next to views.py for example) and make it a module by including an (empty) `__init__.py` file. That's all, after restarting your server, Django will find it.

Comment: My `lookup` function returns the python value for the `key`, if that's a dictionary it returns that. If you want to iterate over that dictionary's keys and values, you could create a second filter, `def items(struct)`, that doesn't take any argument and returns the iterable `.items()` of the dictionary, so then you could do `{% for key, value in show_dataset|lookup:date_key|items %}`